# C++ catch constructor exception

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

I do not seem to understand how to catch constructor exception.
Here is relevant code:

```
     struct Thread {
            rysq::cuda::Fock fock_;
            template<class iterator>
            Thread(const rysq::cuda::Centers &centers,
                   const iterator (&blocks)[4])
                : fock_()
            {
                if (!fock_) throw;
           }
      };

      Thread *ct;
      try { ct = new Thread(centers_, blocks); }
      catch(...) { return false; } // catch never happens,
```

So catch statement do not execute and I get unhandled exception.
What did I do wrong?  this is straight C++ using g++.

Comment: Did you check whether `!fock_` *can* actually evaluate to `true`? Maybe you're simply never throwing an exception in the first place...

Comment: @stakx the exception is thrown, but not caught. I did not know you have to throw explicit exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to throw an object, e.g.,

```
throw std::exception();
```

`throw` with no operand is only used inside of a `catch` block to rethrow the exception being handled by the `catch` block.

Comment: Minor nitpick: it need not be an object. Primitives are okay too.

Comment: @Billy:  in C++, primitives are objects too.  An object is simply "a region of storage" (that's somewhere in the very beginning of the language standard).

Comment: I'd also argue that throwing primitives, while perfectly legal from the language's point of view, would most likely violate the principle of least surprise and make the catch code even more messy than it usually is.

Comment: to clearify: `5` isn't an object. Only what is actually thrown and caught is an object (which can be copy of the expression operand).

Answer (score 3):

You have to throw something in order to catch anything.

Try changing the line

```
if (!fock_) throw;
```

to

```
if (!fock_) throw "";
```

and observe the difference.

Answer (score 3):

You need to throw something. `throw` alone means to "re-throw" the current exception. If there is no current exception, `unexpected` gets called, which will probably abort your program.

It's best to pick a class from `<stdexcept>` that describes the problem. `logic_error` or a derivative to indicate programming mistakes, or `runtime_error` to denote exceptional conditions.